# jboss 5.0.1 doesnt support hot deployment?

Tags: jboss5.x

when i hot deploy a bean jar , it doesnt works. it needs a Jboss restart. hot deployment works fine with Jboss 4.2.2. but Jboss 5.0.1 doesnt support hot deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default hot deployment is turned on for all JBoss versions. For JBoss 5.X check if you have proper configuration in $JBOSS_HOME/server/xxx/deploy/hdscanner-jboss-beans.xml file.

That's the theory however. In JBoss 5.0.X I had a serious issues with hot deployment mechanism, for instance I could deploy application only one time, the redeployment demanded server restart (as in your case). This issue is partly gone in JBoss 5.1, so if you can upgrade to that version.

You can also try theoretically the savest method of deployment through managed beans facility:

$JBOOS_HOME/bin/twiddle invoke "jboss.system:service=MainDeployer" deploy /my/path/to/app/myapp.ear

Also make sure if your JAR file is proper, configuration files are properly formulated. JBoss 5.X is much more restrictive then previous versions when it comes to configuration files. For istance in JBoss 4.X persistence.xml file need not have XML Schema declaration, in JBoss 5.X it is required, etc.

Comment: thanks... and yes jboss5.x is much more complex than jboss 4.x for some cases.